# How to properly generate resources and routes with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to define a resource and route like this with Ember CLI.

```
    this.resource('events', function() {
        this.route('view', { path: "/:id"})
    });
```

If I try this: `ember g resource events/view` I get this:

```
this.resource('events/view', { path: 'events/views/:events/view_id' });
```

If I try this: `ember g resource events`
and: `ember g resource events/view`

```
this.resource('events', { path: 'events/:events_id' });
this.resource('events/view', { path: 'events/views/:events/view_id' });
```

If I try this: `ember g resource events`
and: `ember g route events/view`

```
this.resource('events', { path: 'events/:events_id' });
this.route('events/view');
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At this time, nested resources and routes in the pattern that you desire, are not automatically generated with the default blueprints found in Ember CLI.  The default blueprints generate skeletal files and file structure, and some use their `afterInstall` hook to update other files.  Following these default blueprints, you are properly generating these items:

```
    ember g resource events
    ember g route events/view
```

You could then modify Router.map in router.js with your intended nesting:

```
    Router.map(function() {
      this.resource('events', function() {
        this.route('view', { path: "/view/:id" });
      })
    });
```

You should now be able to hit 'events/view/1' in your browser, and see the routes you've been looking for in the [Ember Inspector's](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) Routes tab.

Alternatively, you could execute the following, and generate a custom blueprint:

```
    ember generate blueprint nested-resource-route
```

A blueprint directory will be created in your project root, with your new blueprint inside.  Using the resource and route blueprints as a foundation, you could roll your own generator to accomplish what you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you for spelling all of this out.  I was running into Ember 101 issues trying to figure out resources vs routes, especially when it came to nesting, and this is exactly what I needed to fix the issue and understand the original problem.

Answer (score 11):

The behavior you want is possible in ember-cli 0.1.5 and later.  From the [release notes](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.5):

> [#2748](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2748) improved  the router generator to support properly nested
>   routes and  resources, previously if you had a route similar like:
>
> ```
> Router.map(function() {
>   this.route("foo");
> });
> ```
>
> And you did  `ember g route foo/bar`  the generated routes would be
>
> ```
> Router.map(function() {
>   this.route("foo");
>   this.route("foo/bar");
> });
> ```
>
> Now it keeps manages nested routes properly so the result would be:
>
> ```
> Router.map(function() {
>   this.route("foo", function() {
>     this.route("bar");
>    }); 
> });
> ```
>
> Additionally the option  `--path`  was added so you can do things like `ember g route friends/edit --path=:friend_id/id`  creating a nested 
>   route under  `friends`  like:  `this.route('edit', {path: ':friend_id/edit'})`